# OS X 10.6.3 wrong system time

Tags: macos, time

I am using Mac OS X 10.6.3. I also have Windows 7 installed on the same machine.

The clock on Mac OS X keeps on gaining time. I have set the proper timezone both in windows as well in Mac OS X.

Any help in resolving this problem?

Comment: What's your version of Bootcamp ?

Answer (score 1):

This can help you :

> I found a better solution to this
>   whole thing. The problem with the
>   Windows clock being off is because the
>   hardware clock (the one on your actual
>   motherboard) is being set to
>   "Universal" time, or GMT, when you
>   shut down your MacOS bootup. When you
>   boot Windows, Windows assumes your
>   clock is set to your local timezone
>   because that's what Windows does by
>   default. This explains why the people
>   who set their MacOS clock to GMT got
>   the right time in Windows... If the
>   hardware clock is being set to "GMT,"
>   when it's actually the local time,
>   Windows will pick this setting up as
>   local time as it did before.
>
> To fix this, you need to add a key to
>   your Windows system registry to tell
>   Windows that your hardware clock will
>   always be GMT.
>
> *** WARNING: Editing your registry improperly can render your Windows
>   installation inoperable. Proceed VERY
>   carefully. I am not responsible if you
>   mess something up. ***
>
> The short solution for people who know
>   how to edit the registry: A DWORD key
>   called
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro
>   l\TimeZoneInformation\RealTimeIsUniversal
>   needs to have the value of "1"
>
> The step-by-step solution is as
>   follows:
>   1. Boot Windows
>
> 2. Click Start --> Run and type regedit. Click OK
> 3. The Windows Registry Editor should pop up. Navigate within the explorer
>      to:
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro
>      l\TimeZoneInformation
> 4. Click on the TimeZoneInformation "folder" from the navigation pane if
>      you haven't already done so.
> 5. This assumes the correct key doesn't exist. If it does, you will
>      just change the existing key's value:
>      Right click on the white space within
>      the folder (If you don't have a right
>      mouse button, you may need to download
>      a program called applemouse to emulate
>      the "control-click" of the apple
>      1-button mouse). Select new --> DWORD
>      Value. Title the key
>      "RealTimeIsUniversal" (No quotes). Set
>      the value to "1" (No quotes again).
>      Hexidecimal should be fine.
> 6. Either reboot and set the clock in MacOS or set the clock in Windows. You
>      should now be able to reboot into
>      either OS and have a correct clock.

Comment: Just wanted to make it clear that the problem is in Mac OS X. Windows is showing properly. I am not clear why should I be tweaking windows settings when the problem is in OS X. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not a situation where you can tell who is wronf and who is right. The fact is that the 2 OS's are stepping each other on their feet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 'Set date and time automatically' checked (under Date & Time > Date & Time in Settings)? If so, your Windows install may not have the correct time.

Comment: Yes, it is checked.
My win 7 install also has the correct time.